# How to Programmatically go back to a Tab Activity from sub activity

Tags: android-intent, android-tabhost, android-tabs

I created 4 tabs using tabHost in my application,when i click a button in the the first tabActivity(Request.class), it will go to another class called Edit.class,
I want to go back from Edit.class to Request.class
i tried intent to pass from one activity to another

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Edit.this,Request.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

it worked, but it doesnt show the tabs in the Request class, it load only the xml corresponding to Request.class.
How to solve this?

```
                   |Tab1|Tab2|Tab3|Tab4|

                     |
                Edit.class
```

Here Tab1 is the Request.class, I need to go back from Edit.class to Request.class, How it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

         Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
             startActivity(i);  

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```